# Owned entity is not loaded in linq query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

Entity:

```
public class Message 
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        ....

        public virtual ICollection<Recipient> Recipients { get; set; }
    }

[Owned]
    public class Recipient 
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        ....
        public string EmailAddress{get;set;}
    }

    public class UserMessage
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        ....
        public Guid MessageId { get; set; }
    }
```

My query:

```
    from u in context.UserMessage 
    join m in context.Message.Include(m=>m.Recipients) on u.MessageId equals m.Id
    where u.Id == @id && m.Recipients.Any(r=>r.EmailAddress.Equals(@recipientEmail))
    select m
```

It just not return any result, even though I'm sure the recipient email address is right.
Did I miss anything here? Why the Recipients is not loaded?

Comment: Do query without the WHERE and check results.  make sure r.EmailAddress and recipientEmail are both strings.

Comment: Without where it returns the message data. r.EmailAddress and recipientEmail are both strings. I changed it to equals, still no luck

Comment: What about ID?   Do you get matches if you remove the ID test?  Is u.Id and @id both Guid?

Comment: Id is good for sure.

Comment: If remove m.Recipients.Any(r=>r.EmailAddress.Equals(@recipientEmail)), it returns result.

Comment: What about the opposite?  Remove id and try just email.

Comment: `r=>r.EmailAddress == recipientEmail`, make sure your expectation is correct first. Also you don't need to `include` if you are querying against database